# I have been trying to read from a .txt using C++ but nothing gets outputted

Tags: c++11, command-line-arguments, ifstream, wsl-2

I need help reading from a .txt file on C++. The code I wrote is supposed to take in command line arguments, one of which is the name of the file, read the file, store its contents in a string and print the content of that string as output. I am using the Ubuntu WSL 2 terminal. And whenever I run the code, it takes in the commands using the arguments and opens the file without issues but doesn't print anything out. I don't know what to do.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    string filename = argv[1];

    cout << filename << endl; 

    string myText;
    ifstream myReadFile;
    
    myReadFile.open(filename);
    

    while(getline (myReadFile, myText)){
        cout << myText; 
    }

    cout << "Why is my code not doing what it is meant to?" << endl;
    myReadFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

That is what was in the file that was supposed to be printed out using `cout`.

```
The man in the mirror does not exist.
```

Comment: Check following condition after opening the file: `if(!myReadFile){cout<<"File not opened";}`

Comment: How do you know it opens the file without issue? You haven’t checked that in your code.

Comment: In your question, you wrote: `"and opens the file without issues"` -- What makes you think that the file was successfully opened? You are not testing whether it was opened successfully or not. In order to test this, you can add the line `if ( myReadFile.fail() ) { cout << "Error opening file!\n"; return 1; }` immediately after the line `myReadFile.open(filename);`.

Comment: I'd be surprised if `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` was truly necessary.

Comment: For fun use an absolute path to the file. If that works then you need to figure out where your working directory is so you can put the file there or modify the working directory to open it with a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way to read lines from a stream is this:

```
ifstream filein(filename);

for (string line; getline(filein, line); ) 
{
    cout << line << endl;
}
```

Notes:

1. No `close()`. C++ takes care of resource management for you when used idiomatically.
2. Use the free `getline`, not the stream member function.